# Select all rows with multiple possible values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get all fields from the product table (*) that have the following set of sub_property:

subprop_name=X
subprop_value=Y

I have the following tables :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/stzhV.jpg (couldn't upload the picture because the format was not accepted)

So, for an example, if I have two products which has in their sub_property table a entry like this:
subprop_name=X
subprop_value=Y

I would like to return it. As described by the schema, a product can have multiple sub_property entries!

So far, this is what I have:

```sql
SELECT prod_id,prod_name from product WHERE product.prod_id IN
(
    SELECT property.product_prod_id FROM property WHERE property.prop_id IN
    (
        SELECT property_prop_id from sub_property WHERE
        (
            sub_property.subprop_name="Type de scanner" AND sub_property.subprop_value="par transparence"
        )
        OR
        (
            sub_property.subprop_name="Pages/minute maximum" AND subprop_value="8.5 pages"
        )
    )
)
```

But obviously, it doesn't work because of the 'OR'.

It returns me all items that have one of the set of sub_property instead of all the products that have all the sets of sub_property.

DATABASE [HERE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t6RrnhDPQuEamjf2bTxFeX/4)

Comment: Why not Just use select * from tbl where colA = 'valX' or colA = 'valY'

Comment: Because I need the products, that have all the sets of sub_properties.

Comment: Can you provide example data? Maybe on  db-fiddle.com? Its hard to test without having data :(

Comment: Yes, I understand, but it's quiet a large database. Shell I create an account for you to test on it?

Comment: Just provide the tables and some example rows (not real data), so everyone can easy test it. You dont need to create an account on db-fiddle.com to provide an example, just press "save" on top and share the generated link here :-)

An example from "db-fiddle.com" for a different issue: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dGqEfRyWjHKLCwVG3pnA4T/4

On the left side table definition and some example rows and on the right side your select query.

Comment: Alright, thanks, sorry for taking so long, there it is : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t6RrnhDPQuEamjf2bTxFeX/1

Comment: That is the way, now, just include some sample data and remove the tables that are not relevant and all will be nice to test.

Comment: I just did that right now

Comment: You have to update your `fiddle` and post the new (updated) link...

Comment: Sorry, there it is : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t6RrnhDPQuEamjf2bTxFeX/4

Comment: I used and approach using INNER JOIN, is something like this what you need? https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t6RrnhDPQuEamjf2bTxFeX/5

Comment: Damn it ! That's it ! That's really it ! Thank you so much and merry Christmass !

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 2:**

I would suggest to use LEFT JOIN for each property and each sub_property and then check the value inside WHERE condition:

```
SELECT product.prod_id, product.prod_name
FROM product 
LEFT JOIN property AS property_a ON property_a.product_prod_id = product.prod_id AND
                                    property_a.prop_name = "PROPERTY_GROUP_3"
LEFT JOIN sub_property AS sub_property_a ON sub_property_a.property_prop_id = property_a.prop_id AND 
                                            sub_property_a.subprop_name="property_4"
LEFT JOIN property AS property_b ON property_b.product_prod_id = product.prod_id AND
                                    property_b.prop_name = "PROPERTY_GROUP_4"
LEFT JOIN sub_property AS sub_property_b ON sub_property_b.property_prop_id = property_b.prop_id AND 
                                            sub_property_b.subprop_name="property_3"
WHERE sub_property_a.subprop_value="value_of_property_4" AND 
      sub_property_b.subprop_value="value_of_property_3"
GROUP BY product.prod_id
```

Example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wk344Gt6hm98xEhM4jei92/6

**Example with 2 new "KEYS" (Index) for better performance:**

```
ALTER TABLE `property`
 ... ADD KEY `prop_name` (`prop_name`);

ALTER TABLE `sub_property`
 ... ADD KEY `subprop_name` (`subprop_name`);
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wk344Gt6hm98xEhM4jei92/7

**Example with INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN**

*I see no difference with EXPLAIN on test data, maybe Mysql optimizer handles this internal equal*

```
SELECT product.prod_id, product.prod_name
FROM product 
INNER JOIN property AS property_a ON property_a.product_prod_id = product.prod_id AND
                                     property_a.prop_name = "PROPERTY_GROUP_3"
INNER JOIN sub_property AS sub_property_a ON sub_property_a.property_prop_id = property_a.prop_id AND 
                                             sub_property_a.subprop_name="property_4" AND
                                             sub_property_a.subprop_value="value_of_property_4"
INNER JOIN property AS property_b ON property_b.product_prod_id = product.prod_id AND
                                     property_b.prop_name = "PROPERTY_GROUP_4"
INNER JOIN sub_property AS sub_property_b ON sub_property_b.property_prop_id = property_b.prop_id AND 
                                             sub_property_b.subprop_name="property_3" AND
                                             sub_property_b.subprop_value="value_of_property_3"
GROUP BY product.prod_id
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wk344Gt6hm98xEhM4jei92/8

Comment: Sadly, 0 rows returned :( !

Comment: Thx for example data :) i have updated my answer. Maybe this solution works for you.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Also, Merry Christmas !

Answer (score 0):

So... I am not sure if it's the correct way to validate two answers, but I got 2 working answers.

This is the first one from @Steff Mächtel using LEFT JOIN (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53915792/5454875)

And the second one is from @Shidersz (see comments below the original question), using INNER JOIN)

"*I used and approach using INNER JOIN, is something like this what you need? db-fiddle.com/f/t6RrnhDPQuEamjf2bTxFeX/5*"

**EDIT**

@Shidersz solution doesn't work because it selects all products who as at least one of the condition, wich I don't want. I want the product to have all the conditions.

Comment: The question, do you need "OR" for the properties or  an "AND" solution? :D
@Shidersz solution uses "OR" in WHERE condition. Which means you get all products if one of the conditions matches. Is that what you want? Or you want only products which both conditions matches? Then you can use my solution.

Comment: Woupsi ! I just found out that your solution works, but due to multiplies JOIN's, I can't really use your solution because it takes forever to load an item. And the time between results increase quiet rapidly. Do you know how you can make your query faster ?

Comment: I have updated my answer a little bit (Left joins to property have an additional AND property_a.prop_name = "PROPERTY_GROUP_3" condition).
You can use "EXPLAIN" to find the bottlenecks. Here is an example output of explain: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wk344Gt6hm98xEhM4jei92/5
You can see possible keys and non of them can be used. You can add additional index for your fields "subprob_name", "prob_name", etc. and check with "EXPLAIN" if this keys are used. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html

Answer (score 0):

Using JOIN's and an `IN` for the tupples could be a simple solution for this.

```
SELECT p.prod_id, p.prod_name
FROM product p
JOIN property AS prop 
  ON prop.product_prod_id = p.prod_id
JOIN sub_property AS subprop 
  ON subprop.property_prop_id = prop.prop_id
WHERE (subprop.subprop_name, subprop.subprop_value) IN (
  ('Type de scanner', 'par transparence'), 
  ('Pages/minute maximum', '8.5 pages')
)                          
GROUP BY p.prod_id, p.prod_name
```